# Find first occurrence of any one of the array elements in a string - Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

The problem is to find the position of the very first occurrence of any of the elements of an array.

```
$terms = @("#", ";", "$", "|");

$StringToBeSearched = "ABC$DEFG#";
```

The expected output needs to be: 3, as '$' occurs before any of the other $terms in the $StringToBeSearched variable

Also, the idea is to do it in the least expensive way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
# Define the characters to search for as an array of [char] instances ([char[]])
# Note the absence of `@(...)`, which is never needed for array literals,
# and the absence of `;`, which is only needed to place *multiple* statements
# on the same line.
[char[]] $terms = '#', ';', '$', '|'

# The string to search trough.
# Note the use of '...' rather than "...", 
# to avoid unintended expansion of "$"-prefixed tokens as
# variable references.
$StringToBeSearched = 'ABC$DEFG#'

# Use the [string] type's .IndexOfAny() method to find the first 
# occurrence of any of the characters in the `$terms` array.
$StringToBeSearched.IndexOfAny($terms)  # -> 3
```

Comment: Hi @mklement0, a quick question on your suggestion to not use ';' unless a line has multiple statements. As you can probably tell, its a force of habit that I'm used to from other programming languages, and actually think of it as best practice to use it. Is there a specific reason its discouraged in Powershell scripting if used, even for a single statement?

Comment: @NoRestartOnUpdate: On the plus side, it has no ill effects at runtime. Conversely, however, it's hard to justify it as best practice, since it is never required and therefore adds visual clutter to the code, which others may find distracting, and which is often a symptom of unfamiliarity with the PowerShell language (trying to use it as if it were C#).